# Facebook login with androidx

Tags: facebook-login, androidx

I am trying to implementing facebook login with androidx but I am getting the following problem while adding facebook dependancy.i have tried alot of things but did nit worked

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

here is my Gradle

```
dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    //used for dimensions
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    // camera view
    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-beta05'

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    }

    //recyclerview
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
    implementation project(path: ':imagecropper')
    implementation project(path: ':amazons3library')


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

//
//    // facebook SDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.1.1'

}
```

please help :(

Comment: How are you bro?) I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: my problem was: my project was not properly in converted androidx. @qw1nz